# PowerCLI Install fails

Tags: powershell, vmware

When I try to install PowerCLI in PowerShell with the command :
Install-Module VMware.PowerCLI

I get following error message :

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : Für die angegebenen Suchkriterien und den Paketnamen "VMware.PowerCLI" wurde keine
>   Übereinstimmung gefunden. Verwenden Sie Get-PSRepository, um alle verfügbaren, registrierten Paketquellen anzuzeigen.
>   In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 Zeichen:21
>   + ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
>   Blockquote

Comment: Where is the source package located?

Answer (score 0):

Check your repo

```
PS /> Get-PSRepository

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

Then try to install again

```
PS /> Install-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI
```

If possible, give us the ENGLISH error message, I don't know what your error message is talking about, maybe my reply is totally out of subject...